# Does the Stanford NLP Parser have methods for semantic role labelling?

Tags: stanford-nlp, semantic-analysis

I'm trying to find the semantic labels of english sentences.
I am using the Stanford NLP parser. Does it have methods for this?

I was going through the documentation but the closest thing I could find was:

```
CoreAnnotations.SemanticWordAnnotation
CoreAnnotations.SemanticTagAnnotation
```

Comment: You should approve @Sebastian's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, we currently don't have a semantic role labeling (SRL) system in CoreNLP.

Unless you already have a system that explicitly requires semantic role labels, I would recommend taking a look at the [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/) representation. Despite the fact that this representation is primarily a syntactic representation, it also encodes a lot semantics and works just as well as SRL for many semantic tasks.

If this alternative does not work for you, then there also exist several SRL systems from other research groups, e.g. the [SRL system from UIUC](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/Curator).

Comment: Is this still true in 2023?