# re: Does Stanford NLP support Shadow Semantic Parsing

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am working with NLP on my project, and I have used the Stanford NLP for tokenization and NER. I am now interested in SRL, I'd like to ask if Stanford NLP supports shadow Semantic Parsing ? If it does, then where could I get it in term of maven or Jar Files , and the support model files if there are any?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, it doesn't. See the following post for a more detailed answer:

[Does the Stanford NLP Parser have methods for semantic role labelling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118160/does-the-stanford-nlp-parser-have-methods-for-semantic-role-labelling/31122774#31122774)